# How to : Websocket request to HTTP api server with websockify

Tags: javascript, websocket, websockify

I have an http API server (returning json data) and a client who make websockets requests, so I decided to go over [websockify](https://github.com/novnc/websockify) to communicate between my server and my client.

But I don't figure how to get the result of a websocket request.

For testing purpose, I have a simple hello world python API server with Flask :

```
import flask
from flask import request, jsonify
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True
result = {"HelloWorld" : 42}
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return jsonify(result)
app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

Tested in a browser, returning well `{"HelloWorld": 42}`.

I run websockify in order to open a new port which communicate with websockets like this : `websockify --verbose 0.0.0.0:5001 0.0.0.0:5000`.

And I have a javascript client who try to make a websocket request like this :

```
var socket = null;
socket = new WebSocket("ws://0.0.0.0:5001/");
socket.onerror = function(error) {
    console.error(error);
};
socket.onopen = function(event) {
    console.log("Connexion ok.");
    socket.send("GET / HTTP/1.1");
};
socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log("Message: ", event.data);
};
socket.onclose = function(event) {
    console.log("Connexion ko.");
};
```

But when I try to execute this script, the connection close immediately after the connection :

```
Connexion ok.
Connexion ko.
```

It seems that it close when I try to send the websocket (`socket.send("GET / HTTP/1.1");`) because if I comment this line then the connection persists.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need something like this:

websockify --verbose 5001 localhost:5000